# Modal window with dynamic height and footer

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have a modal window whose size is dynamic and it has a scroll. The problem is that I can’t see the footer because the data list fills all the screen. I want to see all the time the footer.

Any idea?

Here is my css code:

```css
.own-modal { 
          @media (min-height: 320px) { 
            ion-backdrop { 
              visibility: visible; 
             } 
          }

          position: absolute; 
          top: 0;
          right: 0; 
          bottom: 0; 
          left: 0; 
          display: flex; 
          align-items: center; 
          justify-content: center;
          contain: strict; 
          
          .modal-wrapper { 
              &, .ion-page, 
              .ion-page .content, 
              .ion-page .content .scroll-content { 
                contain: content; 
                position: relative; 
                top: auto; 
                left: auto; 
             } 
           
             display: flex; 
             overflow: auto; 
             flex-direction: column; 
             max-height: 100%; 
             opacity: 0; 
             height: auto; 
             max-width: 100%; 
         } 
    }
```

The modal window content is very simple. In the content I have label and an ion-list and I have a footer with a div and inside an item with a button.

Comment: Where is your codes ?

Comment: I just formatted css code now, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to see the footer all the time then you should use the position fixed:

```
footer {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0;
```

}

Comment: With position: fixed it does not work for me, but I found a solution related, position: sticky :)

Answer (score 0):

With the next code the footer is static at the end of the window. Put it on the end of the file:

ion-footer { position: sticky; }

More info about this property:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp